# Translating AppleScript to Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, nstask

I am new to Objective-C and I am trying to translate an AppleScript into Objective-C. Using AStranslate, I get the error `Untranslated event 'sysoexec'`

The following is the applescript I want to translate:

```
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/'Menu Extras'/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend"
```

I have searched on Google, and people said `NSTask` can be used to simulate the Terminal to run commands. I have tried for a few hours, but cannot figure out how to use `NSTask`. Can someone please help me to translate the AppleScript?

thanks, 
all i want is to have a button to run this terminal command instead of using applescript.

I am still up to 1st lecture of objective C...

i try this and does not seems to work

```
@implementation hopethiswork

- (IBAction)press:(id)sender {

    NSTask *a = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    [a setLaunchPath:@"/System/Library/CoreServices/'Menu Extras'/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession"];
    [a setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"-suspend"]];
    [a launch];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSTask *a = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[a setLaunchPath:@"/System/Library/CoreServices/'Menu Extras'/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession"];
[a setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"-suspend"]];
[a launch];
```

Comment: Don't forget [a release]; if you're not using ARC.

Comment: Parag's answer is the correct one: use NSTask. The OP seems confused about what ASTranslate is for: it's a tool for converting _application commands_ from AppleScript to appscript syntax. It's not a full AS->ObjC code translator - it just sniffs the Apple events sent by AS and reformats them. It won't convert 'do shell script' because that's a scripting addition (OSAX) command, nor will it convert any other code. In any case, Cocoa already includes its own far superior APIs for the sorts of tasks ASers'd use OSAXen for. I suggest the OP gets an intro book on ObjC/Cocoa and starts with that.

Comment: thanks, 
all i want is to have a button to run this terminal command.